# How can I download YouTube audio with Python?

Tags: python, windows, youtube

How can I download the audio from a YouTube video with Windows, using Python 2.7? I have seen many results that work with Linux but I haven't been able to get anything to work with Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884588/streaming-audio-youtube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/). It should work on Linux, windows and OS X.

Comment: thanks, ill check it out and probably give you the Check mark when I have more of a battery life left