# Set custom name and file type youtube_dl python

Tags: python, youtube-dl, m4a

So I want to download the youtube video as "song.m4a", however when I run the following code it gives "song.m4a.webm". How can I fix this?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import os

##Function to download file from youtube
def getYoutube(url):
    ydlOps = {'format': 'bestaudio/best','postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio','preferredcodec': 'm4a','preferredquality': '192',}],'outtmpl':f"{os.getcwd()}/song.m4a"}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydlOps) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
```

Comment: I haven't used `youtube_dl`, but I would bet the problem is related to the double `ydlOps`

Answer (score 0):

I did test your code and on my case it output song.m4a

I think the problem is related to ffmpeg. Or you are missing a codec.

Check this [youtube-dl python script postprocessing error: FFMPEG codecs aren't being recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665160/youtube-dl-python-script-postprocessing-error-ffmpeg-codecs-arent-being-recogn) or post your

Comment: FFmpeg was the problem and I was able to fix the issue, thank you for the help!