# Trying to extract data from another websites permalink. How?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how one would go about  using a permalink from another website to extract data about that particular permalink, especially in the case of looking for specific information. Kind of how youtube has websites that essentially use the link to the video to download and convert it to mp3 format. Its for a college project in HTML5, but upon researching the subject (for about a week) I didnt come up with alot of information on how to go about it using html. Any help in advance will be appreciated. Just basic structure is necessary. im not good or anything, I just want to actually learn, so i need some directional pointing that way i get on the right track.

Thanks in advance :)

Oh and to be more direct, I mean in such a way as to list certain products at the price they are being listed on the site they are being listed on. However, from within my own site. (all in html...)Figured I should be more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Those websites that extract audio from Youtube probably doing it using Python or something similar
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473526/download-only-audio-from-youtube-video-using-youtube-dl-in-python-script) might help you.

Comment: Hmmm what about filling a form out with the data gathered? Like a bunch of items prices, then adding it together? Would this still be done in python? Or could this be done in html

Comment: For that you will need HTML to create the form, PHP or something like it (ASP for example) for processing the data you got from the HTML form, SQL (MySql is recommended) to store the data in a tables and then you can use PHP again to present the results.