# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'youtube_dl' has no attribute 'YoutubeDL' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Every time I run my code, it always shows an error that says:
[image]
my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl


class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)


def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Done downloading, now converting ...')


ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
    'quiet': True,
    'writedescription': True,
    'writethumbnail': True,
    'progress_hooks': True,
    'prefer_ffmpeg': True,
    'ffmpeg_location': 'C:\FFMPEG',
    'keepvideo': True,
    'outtmpl': 'C:/Users/semif/Downloaders/%(uploader)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as Yami:
    Yami.download([input('url: ')])
```

well, you have probably seen some of this because I copied most if not some of these codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842104/youtube-dl-giving-attributeerror-python). I have `Python 3.9.2`. Do I lack something? I tried searching for solutions but have not found any links that answered my problem.

I also want to download the file as mp4...any ideas on how can I do it? because in the code it only specified the mp3 version of the file.

Comment: the link you posted said don't name your file youtube_dl.py

Comment: i change my file name to ytd.py and it showed ```TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [youtube\_dl giving AttributeError (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842104/youtube-dl-giving-attributeerror-python)

Comment: it did remove the attribute error but it showed me a new error: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`