# Extracting audio from youtube video

Tags: python, audio, youtube

What's the easiest way to download the audio from a youtube video? I considered using youtube-dl and extracting the audio from the downloaded video, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Here's the another way to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167197/11663802

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found this thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27481870/13003236
In case any future users stumble across this post