# I have already installed ffmpge but getting following DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one

Tags: python, audio, youtube, youtube-dl

Took help from this thread : [download only audio from youtube video using youtube-dl in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473526/download-only-audio-from-youtube-video-using-youtube-dl-in-python-script)

```
import youtube_dl #installed youtube_dl file

options = {
    'format':'bestaudio/best',
    'extractaudio':True,            #extracting audio
    'audioformat':'mp3',            #file options and format
    'outtmpl':'%(id)s.%(ext)s',     #name the file the ID of the video
    'noplaylist':True,
    'nocheckcertificate':True,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',# Used ffmpeg for converting the file to mp3
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }]
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://youtu.be/BZP1rYjoBgI']) #final downloading
```

[Python console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XEst.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you did not completely install ffmpeg; it must be in your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)). You can check by typing `ffmpeg` in a terminal.

There are multiple possible solutions here:

1. Install ffmpeg into your `PATH`, for example by copying the binary to `/usr/bin/`.
2. Symlink the `ffmpeg` binary to a directory in your `PATH`.
3. Set up your `PATH` so that it contains contains the directory where you installed ffmpeg. On Linux and macOS, [this likely involved editing `~/.profile` or `/etc/environment`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/35070) and logging in again. On Windows, [editing the registry works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546324/35070).
4. Specify the precise ffmpeg location in your configuration by adding `'ffmpeg_location': '/replace/this/with/the/real/path/to/your/ffmpeg'` to your youtube-dl configuration. Naturally this will only fix the problem for youtube-dl, not other applications relying on ffmpeg.