# youtube_dl error ffprobe and ffmpeg not found

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, youtube-dl, ffprobe

I've been using youtube_dl for a while now without any problems.
Since maybe around a week I am always getting the following error when trying to download something and don't know how to fix it:

> ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install
> one.

I am using it in a virtual python 3.8.10 environment with youtube_dl version 2021.12.17, ffmpeg version 1.4 and ffprobe version 0.5 displayed with "pip freeze" command.
The os is ubuntu server 20.04.5 LTS.

I already tried installing ffmpeg in multiple different ways (pip, apt install) and installing it on different "layers" (virtual env, normal user, root user) but nothing seemed to help.

For any tips / suggestions that might help I'd be really glad.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Could you please clairify what you expect me to do with this link @kesh

Comment: Literally what the error message is saying: "Please install one." You need ffmpeg & ffprobe programs on your PC for it to work. (nothing to do with python)

Comment: Make sure FFmpeg CLI and FFprobe (executables) are in the system path. The question is [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63204915/4926757). I am not sure you are going to like the answer... In Ubuntu shell you may use [which](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/which.1.html) command. (e.g. `which ffmpeg`) for locating FFmpeg directory. You may also try [executing shell commands](https://www.the-analytics.club/python-shell-commands) within Python (just for verifying that `ffmpeg` in the system path).